# Flutter - TextField content does not scroll automatically when inserting text

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

everyone! When I use the keyboard to input normally, the content will automatically scroll to the end when the content width exceeds the width of the TextField; but when I use TextEditingController to set the content for the TextField, when the content exceeds the width of the TextField, the content will not automatically scroll to the end.

code show as below

```dart
class _TextFieldPageState extends State<TextFieldPage> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('TextField content not scroll'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: 100,
              child: TextField(
                controller: _controller,
                maxLines: 1,
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // insert 'Flutter'
                  _controller.text += 'Flutter';
                  // change cursor position to end
                  _controller.selection = TextSelection(
                    baseOffset: _controller.text.length,
                    extentOffset: _controller.text.length,
                  );
                },
                child: Text('insert text'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

keyboard input：

[image: keyboard input]

TextEditingController set text:

[image: insert text use TextEditingController]

How to make the content of TextField scroll to the end automatically when inserting text using Controller? thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way worked for me. Change the function of your `onPressed` to this:

```
ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                // insert 'Flutter'

                _editingController.text += 'Flutter1';
                await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 10));
                _scrollController
                    .jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
                print("Jumpted");
                _focusNode.unfocus();
                await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 10));
                _focusNode.requestFocus();
              },
              child: Text('insert text'),
            )
```

And the text field to this:

```
TextField(
                controller: _editingController,
                focusNode: _focusNode,
                scrollController: _scrollController,
                maxLines: 1,
              )
```

The main thing to know is that TextField has another controller called `ScrollController` [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html) which can be used to attain the outcome you seek.

Ps: don't forget to declare the scroll and focus variables

```
 final TextEditingController _editingController = TextEditingController();
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
```

Answer (score 1):

add `FocusNode` like this:

```
FocusNode myFocusNode = FocusNode();

return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      SizedBox(
        width: 100,
        child: TextField(
          focusNode: myFocusNode,
          controller: _controller,
          maxLines: 1,
        ),
      ),
      ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // insert 'Flutter'
            _controller.text += 'Flutter';
            myFocusNode.requestFocus();
            // change cursor position to end
            _controller.selection = TextSelection(
              baseOffset: _controller.text.length,
              extentOffset: _controller.text.length,
            );
          },
          child: Text('insert text'))
    ],
  ),
));
```

the result would look like this:

[image]

Comment: not work, thanks.

Comment: are you sure you added  `myFocusNode.requestFocus();` ?

Comment: I added it, but it doesn't work on mobile.